# Is it possible to use powershell to authenticate AD user so they can log on later offline

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to create a user account in active directory that will be able to log in to any machine in the directory. I have a situation where the first time the user actually touches a machine it will not be on the network, and I don't know ahead of time which machines they will be using.

Normally after creating the user, you have to log in with the account **while the machine is on the network with the directory server** before that account can log in offline.

I know GPO can push powershell scripts and run them.

I would like to push and run a powershell script to all the machines while I have them on the network that would authenticate this user's account so that I don't have to manually log in to it before giving the user a machine.

Is this possible and what help pages would I need to look at?

Comment: This is an infrastructure administration question, not a programming question. The former belong on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). With that said, I don't think you can easily pre-cache credentials.

Comment: "*and I don't know ahead of time which machines they will be using.*" - You want to cache *every* user's credentials on every machine? That sounds like an exploit waiting to happen, when one uses an admin password reset boot cd, and steals the cached credentials. For one user per machine, you could potentially put the password in the autologin reg key and reboot the machine so it logs in, and then remove it from the reg key.

Comment: "ever user's credentials"

No. 1 specific account.

Comment: to clear up my confusion is this infrastructure because it deals with AD or is powershell properly infrastructure?

Comment: I consider it an infrastructure management question, b/c the focus of your question is the management of your infrastructure (how do I pre-cache credentials on computers), not a programming problem (I have problem X with this code/algorithm).

Comment: I appreciate your take on this. I thought it would fit here because I'm looking specifically for help doing it in powershell.